# Failed to connect to seed broker with kafkajs

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafkajs

I am trying to use `kafkajs` in order to create a kafka consumer. However, I get already an error when connecting to kafka:

```
"[BrokerPool] Failed to connect to seed broker, trying another broker from the list: Closed connection"
```

This is the code I am using:

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: [
      "abc123f.xyz.cde.net:9094",
      "abc123h.xyz.cde.net:9094",
      "abc123k.xyz.cde.net:9094"
      ]
})
```

Does anyone has an idea why this error happens or how to solve it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the end it was the missing `ssl: true` parameter. The solution was as follows:

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')

const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  ssl: true,
  brokers: [
      "abc123f.xyz.cde.net:9094",
      "abc123h.xyz.cde.net:9094",
      "abc123k.xyz.cde.net:9094"
      ]
})
```

Comment: What is the clientId here? I have started kafka on my console and want my react code to consume a message.

Comment: @DhirajGandhi This is just a meaningful name you choose for the client application

Comment: If you enabled ssl, don't you also need certs?

Comment: SSL requires certificate and key. This answer seems to be incomplete without info about certs and keys

Comment: @ParzhfromUkraine I think you meant TLS